# GTK+ get file information

Tags: file, gtk

How can i get information from the file's url?

Eg: if i have the file

```
 char *my_file = /home/user/music.mp3
```

How can i retrive:

File's title

artist

album

year

file type

Answer (score 1):

You can use libid3tag for the MP3 stuff. Something like:

```
struct id3_file *id3_file;
struct id3_frame const *frame;
struct id3_tag *tag;
id3_utf8_t *title=NULL;

id3_file = id3_file_open (filename, ID3_FILE_MODE_READONLY);

if (!id3_file)
{
    // fail
    return
}

tag = id3_file_tag (id3_file);
if (!tag) 
{
    // fail
    id3_file_close(id3_file);
    return;
}

/* get tag values */

frame = id3_tag_findframe (tag, ID3_FRAME_TITLE, 0);
if (frame && (field = &frame->fields[1]))
{
        if (id3_field_getnstrings (field) > 0)
        {
                title = id3_ucs4_utf8duplicate (id3_field_getstrings (field, 0));
        }
}

/* ... etc ...*/

id3_file_close (id3_file);
```

Comment: That looks pretty interesting.But that works only with mp3 files right?

Comment: Yes, if you're looking for regular file information, use the Gio library. The GFile object can be created for a URI or a local path. From that you can get all sorts of info from the GFileInfo which you get by calling g_file_query_info() http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFileInfo.html